# Please install package: 'Android Support Library'

Tags: android, package, xamarin, android-support-library, android-sdk-tools

I am coding a Xamarin application and these are the errors that I am getting when building my application:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error XA5206: Please install package: 'Android Support Library' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\Simon\Documents\Xamarin\SimpleOnePageViewPager\SimpleOnePageViewPager\Components\googleplayservicesgingerbread-16.0.0.1\lib\android\19.1.0\content\support/v7/appcompat doesn't exist. (XA5206) (SimpleOnePageViewPager)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error XA5207: Please install package: 'Android Support Library' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\Simon\Documents\Xamarin\SimpleOnePageViewPager\SimpleOnePageViewPager\Components\googleplayservicesgingerbread-16.0.0.1\lib\android\19.1.0\content\support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar doesn't exist. (XA5207) (SimpleOnePageViewPager)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error XA5206: Please install package: 'Android Support Library' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\Simon\Documents\Xamarin\SimpleOnePageViewPager\SimpleOnePageViewPager\Components\googleplayservicesgingerbread-16.0.0.1\lib\android\19.1.0\content\support/v7/mediarouter doesn't exist. (XA5206) (SimpleOnePageViewPager)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error XA5207: Please install package: 'Android Support Library' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\Simon\Documents\Xamarin\SimpleOnePageViewPager\SimpleOnePageViewPager\Components\googleplayservicesgingerbread-16.0.0.1\lib\android\19.1.0\content\support/v7/mediarouter/libs/android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar doesn't exist. (XA5207) (SimpleOnePageViewPager)
```

I have added the `Android Support Library v4` as a component and in the `Android SDK Manager` I seem to have everything installed correctly.

Can I please have some help to get my code building successfully?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I have added the `Android Support Library v7 AppCompat` as a component and am now getting these two errors:

```
Error XA5206: Please install package: 'Android Support Library' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\Simon\Documents\Xamarin\SimpleOnePageViewPager\SimpleOnePageViewPager\Components\googleplayservicesgingerbread-16.0.0.1\lib\android\19.1.0\content\support/v7/mediarouter doesn't exist. (XA5206) (SimpleOnePageViewPager)
Error XA5207: Please install package: 'Android Support Library' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\Simon\Documents\Xamarin\SimpleOnePageViewPager\SimpleOnePageViewPager\Components\googleplayservicesgingerbread-16.0.0.1\lib\android\19.1.0\content\support/v7/mediarouter/libs/android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar doesn't exist. (XA5207) (SimpleOnePageViewPager)
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Same here... If someone solved this please consider answering?

Comment: Fixed it, added a new answer

Comment: refer to answer provide [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443297/xamarin-forms-android-error-please-install-package-android-support-library) on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add android-support-v7-appcompat as library project. It's it sdk android extras.

Comment: Is this found in the Android SDK Manager? I cannot see it.

Comment: It's part of suport library

Answer (score 10):

in case your "embedded" folder is missing, just downloading and extracting the android_m2repository_r10.zip does not solve the issue.

I deleted the entire C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.0.1.3 folder and then rebuild as described here:
[[Error after updating the Android.Support Library v7 AppCompat to the 21.0.3 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437601/error-after-updating-the-android-support-library-v7-appcompat-to-the-21-0-3-vers][1])

Answer (score 8):

I solved all of the 'Please install Android Support Library' errors, although I'm not sure which step exactly solved it. However, this is what I did in case someone has the same trouble as I did:

- Download "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r10.zip " and paste it in "C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\21.0.3\". For mac users change the path pre-Xamarin to \Users\YourUserName\ .local\share\Xamarin (Overwrite as needed, but create backup just in case)
- Extract the contents of the android_m2repository_r10.zip archive into {...}\Android.Support.v4\21.0.3\content folder (create content folder if it doesn't exist, overwrite as needed and take same precautions as above)
- Repeat the steps above but this time for the {...}\Android.Support.v4\22.2.0 folder instead of the 21.0.3
- Make sure you have your packages updated to the latest version by right clicking on the Package folder of your solution and clicking Update (At least on Xamarin Studio).
- Make sure you also have the latest version of Android Support Library on the Android SDK Manager
- In case everything fails, try the AppCompat Android component from Xamarin (your milage may vary with the last one)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same problem and i followed following link and it is working like a charm.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/56627/xamarin-android-support-v7-cardview-error-depite-being-installed

Answer (score 1):

Just suppress the zip in Xamarin\zips{zip} and rebuild your solution .

Comment: What do you mean "suppress the zip"

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to @sgarcia the answer there are another steps that fixes the problem.

1- Renaming the android_m2repository_rnn.zip file to it's MD5 hash of url.Here is a list of some of them:

> android_m2repository_r33.zip -->     5FB756A25962361D17BBE99C3B3FCC44
>   android_m2repository_r32.zip  --> F16A3455987DBAE5783F058F19F7FCDF
>   android_m2repository_r31.zip  --> 99A8907CE2324316E754A95E4C2D786E
>   android_m2repository_r30.zip  --> 05AD180B8BDC7C21D6BCB94DDE7F2C8F
>   android_m2repository_r29.zip  --> 2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41
>   android_m2repository_r28.zip  --> 17BE247580748F1EDB72E9F374AA0223
>   android_m2repository_r27.zip  --> C9FD4FCD69D7D12B1D9DF076B7BE4E1C
>   android_m2repository_r26.zip  --> 8157FC1C311BB36420C1D8992AF54A4D
>   android_m2repository_r25.zip  --> 0B3F1796C97C707339FB13AE8507AF50
>   android_m2repository_r24.zip  --> 8E3C9EC713781EDFE1EFBC5974136BEA
>   android_m2repository_r23.zip  --> D5BB66B3640FD9B9C6362C9DB5AB0FE7
>   android_m2repository_r22.zip  --> 96659D653BDE0FAEDB818170891F2BB0
>   android_m2repository_r21.zip  --> CD3223F2EFE068A26682B9E9C4B6FBB5
>   android_m2repository_r20.zip  --> 650E58DF02DB1A832386FA4A2DE46B1A
>   android_m2repository_r19.zip  --> 263B062D6EFAA8AEE39E9460B8A5851A
>   android_m2repository_r18.zip  --> 25947AD38DCB4865ABEB61522FAFDA0E
>   android_m2repository_r17.zip  --> 49054774F44AE5F35A6BA9D3C117EFD8
>   android_m2repository_r16.zip  --> 0595E577D19D31708195A83087881EE6

You can find the list here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/#Manually_Downloading_m2repository

If the problem still exists the best way is to follow this link's instructions.
[Manually Downloading and Installing m2repository Files](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/#Manually_Downloading_and_Installing_m2repository_Files)

Comment: My issue was that I have moved some folder, so even deleting the files, VS doesn't copy the files to the right folder, so I had to download and uncompress the file in c:\user\myuser\AppData\Local\Xamarin

Answer (score 1):

user998066, simonbassey and sgarcia.dev - thanks.

Just to update, you don't have to manually download those zip's and extract them in your appdata folder. Just delete them and rebuild your solution. Visual Studio will download and do the rest. It doesn't show that its downloading/extracting/watever in the output window (one thinks its frozen and will kill the VS instance.. dont do it as this is where your download is interrupted and the zip file is corrupt and keeps giving those errors.) and takes a lot of time. If you go to C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips you will see the zips getting downloaded while you are building your solution. Its a huge file and your first build will certainly take a lot of time until its downloaded..

Comment: The solution for me was to move the zips from the AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips folder and clean+rebuild the solution. It did take about 5 mins to build and afterwards there was a new zip file in the zips folder - it was about 140MB. The build was successful after this action alone.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the following: 
1- Open Android SDK Manager 
2- Under Tools Tab --> Find the folder "Extras" 
3- Make sure that "Android Support Repository" is installed

Upgrade Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 to 22 or higher. I went on with 25.4.0.2.

Install  Xamarin.Android.Support.v7 and everything just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still facing this problem , try following these steps to resolve it. it did the magic for me

1. Goto the Xamarin installation folder path . on windows you can find it here C:\Users\simonbassey\AppData\Local\Xamarin
2. Next delete the zips folder therein (it may have been corrupt or not an updated version of the support library). Also delete every other Xamarin.Android.Support.* folder there.
3. Head on to the visual studio solutions folder for the project and delete the bin/ and debug/ folders.
4. Restart  visual studio and rebuild your project.

See this [thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/56627/xamarin-android-support-v7-cardview-error-depite-being-installed) for more details

Answer (score 0):

What fixes in my case was:

1- Open Android SDK Manager

2- Find the folder "Extras"

3- Make sure that "Android Support Repository" is installed

Then in VS:

1- clear the obj and bin folder

2- clean and rebuild the solution

Answer (score 0):

Following two links helped me with all jdk and droid project related problems. In case it may help other guys also.

1. [Cleaning particular zips](http://davidyardy.com/archive/xamarin-please-install-package-android-support-library/)
2. [Setting java version](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/62664/error-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-com-android-dx-command-main-createdatabasewithadonet)