# Android Support v4 for xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have updated the Android support from the xamarin studion to the latest version 23.1.1.0 . Now when I am building the program I am again getting the error that "Android Support v4 doesnt exist" . Although When I set up the **xamarin** initially I followed [Xamarin Forms Android Error: Please install package 'Android Support Library'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443297/xamarin-forms-android-error-please-install-package-android-support-library). But now it is not working as it is asking for C:\Users\kaushalkai\AppData\21.1.1\embedded\libs\internal_impl23.1.1.0.jar file..
Please explain me what to be done now?

Comment: Have you also updated the Android SDK? You can check that from inside Xamarin Studio > Tools > Open Android SDK Manager.

Comment: yes ...I have already checked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are changes in how Xamarin.Android compiles the project, so you might have to remove the corrupt zip package in the cache folder and try to compile again.

More technical details can be found in

https://blog.lextudio.com/2016/05/android-support-repository-and-xamarin-android/