# Xamarin Support Package error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-permissions

```
Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\Srinivasarao\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3\embedded\./ doesn't exist.  Sample.Droid

Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\Srinivasarao\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.  Sample.Droid

Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\Srinivasarao\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.0.1.3\embedded\./ doesn't exist.  Sample.Droid

Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\Srinivasarao\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.0.1.3\embedded\libs/internal_impl-23.0.1.jar doesn't exist.    Sample.Droid

Reason: C:\Users\Srinivasarao\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\96659D653BDE0FAEDB818170891F2BB0.zip is not a valid zip file   Sample.Droid
```

Hi Friends I am trying to Execute Sample Xamarin Form App In VisualStudio But i am Getting Above errors. Please Help me. But when i trying to install this version package it is instatting empty folder in this location 'C:\Users\Srinivasarao\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3\'

Comment: Did you install those packages from the Android SDK installer?

Comment: where can i find that packages installed or not.

Comment: Please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38167551/2101822

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Delete all from the path: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Xamarin Folders and Zip files.
And then rebuild your project.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/56627/xamarin-android-support-v7-cardview-error-depite-being-installed

Answer (score 1):

#### Launch Android SDK Manager from Visual Studio

To launch the Android SDK on Windows, navigate to the Tools > Android menu and select Open Android SDK Manager.

The SDK Manager window will open.

You can use this Android SDK manager to select tools, documentation, and the SDK that you wish to download or update.

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/launch_sdk_manager/

#### After ensuring everything is update in Android SDK:

1) Delete the "21.0.3" folder within in your AppData dir (reference your error)

2) Rebuild your application.

Comment: after Rebuild Creating "23.0.1.3" Empty folder.

Answer (score 0):

Download android_m2repository_r25.zip related to API Level 21.0.3 and putit on this path C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Xamarin Folders and Zip and extract it.

i hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

1: Download "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r22.zip" into your (mediafire.com or other upload center websites)

2: Download "android_m2repository_r22.zip" from your mediafire panel into your computer

3: Rebuild your solution to get list of error codes

4: Find error(Error     Reason: "C:\Users\Vahid\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\96659D653BDE0FAEDB818170891F2BB0.zip" is not a valid zip file)

5: Copy your android_m2repository_r22.zip into "C:\Users\Vahid\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\" directory

6: Rename "android_m2repository_r22.zip" to "96659D653BDE0FAEDB818170891F2BB0.zip"

7: Rebuild your solution

8: Enjoy xamarin form.

List of md5 name for your download file are available in "https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/#Manually_Downloading_m2repository"

check https://stackoverflow.com/a/38367810/2920206