# File missing Error while trying to build App in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am getting the following error when trying to build MyApp.Droid in Xamarin.
Can somebody please explain why am I getting this error and where can I find the specified jar file.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available
>   in SDK installer. Java library file
>   C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded\libs/internal_impl-23.3.0.jar
>   doesn't exist.    MyApp.Droid

Comment: Did you install the support libary using the android SDK manager?

Comment: yes, I have installed it.

Comment: Please follow these steps written at following thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/37827122/2034822

Answer (score 1):

When this happens it means some build went wrong and for some reason maybe the support packages weren't currently downloaded and installed on your machine.

You can clean the local cache like Andres Castro said above, and then rebuild your project.

Also always make sure you have all Android SDK updated to the latest versions and that the packages for support libraries are the same that Xamarin Forms depends on.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue the other day. There was a [Xamarin Forum post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17349/compilation-error-unzipping-failed-please-download-https-dl-since-xamarin-studio-v5-0-upgrade) that helped me find a solution.

What worked for me was to delete everything under C:\Users\AppData\Local\Xamarin\ and then do clean and rebuild. If on a mac that folder will be under /Users/UserName/.local/share/Xamarin

Comment: yes, I tried deleting and then rebuilding the app but it gives an error that unzip failed and is unable to copy the specified jar file.

Is there a way to manually download and add those files

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1) download this file https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r19.0.1.zip

2) Unzip it into a location of your choosing

3) create the following directory C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\content

4) copy the unzipped directory into this new content folder

5) in file explorer (windows) go to C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Xamarin

6) create the same directory structure and content for the other directories at this level

your directories should look something like ...\23.3.0.0\content\m2_repository\ .  When you build the solutions the folders ...\23.3.0.0\embedded etc will be automatically created

I have had to do this many many times, for reasons I do not understand