# Hundreds of Resource.Designer.cs build errors on latest Xamarin Forms 2.2.0.45

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a new Xamarin Forms solution setup with a PCL, an iOS app (which builds fine), and an Android project. The Android project is up to date with the latest Nuget packages for Xamarin Forms (2.2.0.45) to match the PCL project. However when I build the project I'm getting over 500 errors in the Resource.Designer.cs file.

I've tried all the suggestions that I've found online, such as deleting the file and having it regenerated during the Build. Checking the .csproj file for the  tag and it's there.

Xamarin Forums don't have any answers, some people have filed bug reports. I can't imagine having a clean new Android project on Xamarin Forms won't build. The PCL and iOS app are running fine and have no errors.

Example build output looks like this:

1>C:\MyApp\Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs(39,124,39,130): error CS0117: 'Resource.Animation' does not contain a definition for 'fab_in' 1>C:\MyApp\Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs(40,125,40,132): error CS0117: 'Resource.Animation' does not contain a definition for 'fab_out' 1>C:\MyApp\Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs(41,129,41,140): error CS0117: 'Resource.Animation' does not contain a definition for 'snackbar_in' 1>C:\MyApp\Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs(42,130,42,142): error CS0117: 'Resource.Animation' does not contain a definition for 'snackbar_out' 1>C:\MyApp\Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs(87,125,87,132): error CS0117: 'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'barSize' 1>C:\MyApp\Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs(125,145,125,172): error CS0117: 'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'disableChildrenWhenDisabled' 1>C:\MyApp\Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs(192,136,192,154): error CS0117: 'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'middleBarArrowSize' 1>C:\MyApp\Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs(204,133,204,148): error CS0117: 'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'popupPromptView' 1>C:\MyApp\Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs(211,124,211,130): error CS0117: 'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'prompt' 1>C:\MyApp\Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs(228,129,228,140): error CS0117: 'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'spinnerMode' 1>C:\MyApp\Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs(282,139,282,160): error CS0117: 'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'topBottomBarArrowSize' 1>C:\MyApp\Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs(337,121,337,132): error CS0117: 'Resource.Color' does not contain a definition for 'error_color'

Comment: And you have the latest SDK(s) installed, specifically API 23?

Comment: Yes, I have the latest SDK API 23 installed, and have these properties set in my Android Manifest.

Comment: Are you using XLabs?

Comment: No, I'm not using XLabs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by installing these Nuget packages -Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, Xamarin.Android.Support.v13, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.GridLayout, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, Xamarin.Android.Support.v8.RenderScript, Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable, and also @Clowning answer of adding a partial class for the missing resources. CHECKED IN, NEVER TO TOUCH NUGET ON THIS PROJECT AGAIN!

Answer (score 2):

Check your android sdk manager and uninstall all Android SDK Build Tools except for the lastest and greatest

Close Visual Studio
and Delete Everything in this folder and C:\Users\YOURUSER\AppData\Local\Xamarin\

Reopen Project And Rebuild Solution and visual Studio will re-download files needed back in that folder and you should be set to go

Comment: Thanks, already did those things and didn't fix any of the errors. See my answer I just posted. It's just missing Nuget packages (Android Support packages)

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this problem very recently, Follow these steps =>

- Clean your solution, build again then you will see these kind of
     errors in outpust " Please install package: 'Android Support
     Library' available in SDK installer. Java library file

  > C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\21.0.3\embedded\classes.jar
  >       doesn't exist.    MyProject.Droid"

  then please follow this question
  [[Xamarin Forms Android Error: Please install package 'Android Support Library'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443297/xamarin-forms-android-error-please-install-package-android-support-library/31794119#31794119][1])
- Please update your package but keep in mind that package version
  should depend on the version of Xamarin Forms you have installed.
- At last if problem still persists with some strings then cross
  check the components updates and build tools version from the android
  sdk managers.

It was quite a long process and you have to hit/try for this with the correct packages installation.

Comment: I'm not seeing those errors. I'm only getting errors with the Resource.Designer.cs file. I've deleted it, cleaned the solution, rebuilt which regenerates the file, added it back to the project. built again and it breaks with 533 errors. Uninstalled all Nuget packages and reinstalled Xamarin.Forms 2.2.0.45 which installs some dependencies but same errors.