# Xamarin android app throws ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: android, xaml, f#, xamarin.android

Since 1 week I discovered Xamarin framework, and my job is to make Android app work. iOS app has been already launched before.

I had to deal first with some NuGet Packages dependencies, but now the only exception I get is :

```
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (JniObjectReference instance, JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x000a7] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:12083 
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:444 
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FinishCreateInstance (IntPtr instance, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr constructorId, Android.Runtime.JValue* constructorParameters) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:339 
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at Android.Support.V4.App.ActionBarDrawerToggle..ctor (Android.App.Activity activity, Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Int32 drawerImageRes, Int32 openDrawerContentDescRes, Int32 closeDrawerContentDescRes) [0x00124] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.GetNewMasterDetailToggle () [0x00030] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.UpdateMasterDetailToggle (Boolean update) [0x00075] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.UpdateActionBar () [0x000a6] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.SetPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page newRoot) [0x000bd] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity.InternalSetPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page page) [0x000b7] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity.SetMainPage () [0x0000c] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity.LoadApplication (Xamarin.Forms.Application application) [0x0002d] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at savtime.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x0001e] in D:\sources\savtime-mobile\Droid\MainActivity.cs:27 
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2426 
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:72e9ca78-aec6-45d3-82e8-45b117f59475 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1243)
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:766)
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:402)
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.<init>(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:277)
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.<init>(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:229)
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at md5daa929973e91d615883be6545c9acbac.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at md5daa929973e91d615883be6545c9acbac.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5975)
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
06-26 15:01:40.719 E/mono-rt (20038):   at android.os
```

I saw many posts here and it seems to be an icon problem, but i've checked all resource definitions in the project, resource names, and everything seems to be fine.

Is it possible that this problem is caused by bad References (Like Xamarin Forms, or Iconize) ? Or this can be only because of missing resources ?

I've already clean my solution updated or downgraded my packages but nothing work..

I must also indicate that I use F# instead of C# to develop. And my views are made with XAML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found what is the problem.

First, I must set for all my resources files 'AndroidResource' in Build Action field (See in properties when you select a resource)

Second, I must not use other characters as A to Z, 0 to 9, and '_' to name my resources.

Comment: for me, it was having my image name in camel case

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to resolve issue -

1. I was missing "Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" NuGet package so I included it in my android project.For me correct version was 23.3.0 but it may be diffrent in your case.
2. Deleted obj and bin folder for my android project.
3. Restarted visual studio.
4. Rebuild

Comment: I wasn't missing the vector support package, but geez, the amount of times that "nuke everything, restart, and rebuild" comes up as the solution in Xamarin is quite worrying. Fixed my issue as well after adding a bunch of icon resources...

Answer (score 1):

The way i fixed a similar issue was by cleaning the project, rebuilding it and running it.
Was a great tip from one of my colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

Have You Tried This Delete The Content Out Your C:\Users\YOURUSER\AppData\Local\Xamarin\

[Hundreds of Resource.Designer.cs build errors on latest Xamarin Forms 2.2.0.45](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815357/hundreds-of-resource-designer-cs-build-errors-on-latest-xamarin-forms-2-2-0-45/37841443#37841443)