# Error while compiling project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\Zeeshan Ahmad\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.4.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist. DrawerLayout_V7_Tutorial            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\Zeeshan Ahmad\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.4.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist. DrawerLayout_V7_Tutorial            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\Zeeshan Ahmad\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.4.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist. DrawerLayout_V7_Tutorial            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\Zeeshan Ahmad\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.4.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist. DrawerLayout_V7_Tutorial            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\Zeeshan Ahmad\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.4.0.0\embedded\libs/internal_impl-23.4.0.jar doesn't exist.   DrawerLayout_V7_Tutorial            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\Zeeshan Ahmad\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.4.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist. DrawerLayout_V7_Tutorial            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\Zeeshan Ahmad\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.4.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist. DrawerLayout_V7_Tutorial            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\Zeeshan Ahmad\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.4.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.   DrawerLayout_V7_Tutorial            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\Zeeshan Ahmad\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.4.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.   DrawerLayout_V7_Tutorial            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\Zeeshan Ahmad\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\F16A3455987DBAE5783F058F19F7FCDF.zip is not a valid zip file  DrawerLayout_V7_Tutorial            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\Zeeshan Ahmad\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\F16A3455987DBAE5783F058F19F7FCDF.zip is not a valid zip file  DrawerLayout_V7_Tutorial            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\Zeeshan Ahmad\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\F16A3455987DBAE5783F058F19F7FCDF.zip is not a valid zip file  DrawerLayout_V7_Tutorial            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\Zeeshan Ahmad\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\F16A3455987DBAE5783F058F19F7FCDF.zip is not a valid zip file  DrawerLayout_V7_Tutorial
```

Comment: is the first program that you are create in Xamarin?

Before you are compiling other project without a error?

Comment: the very first line tells you to "Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer"

Comment: I wish my errors were that explicit. I wonder if this is what all questions look like to Skeet.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to resolve these errors are to delete your local caches of these libraries and try downloading again:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/#Automatic_Recovery_from_m2repository_Errors

If you run into issues with automatically downloading them, you can manually download and place these libraries:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/#Manually_Downloading_m2repository

Finally if manually downloading fails, you may need to go the further step of downloading the `m2repository`:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/#install

These docs were written via part of a guide I wrote a few months ago: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/f6291eacd4da5f6aa4cd

You can also see this related question which has the same steps as above:

[Build unsuccessful : Error with Android project in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869051/build-unsuccessful-error-with-android-project-in-xamarin-forms/36215224#36215224)

Answer (score 0):

During first build of your project/solution, please be patient until the MS Build prompts you the results. Please do not cancel the build or do not rebuild the solution until the first build is complete. The first time build actually downloads the libraries in the background.

Inc case after completion of the first time build gives you error, probably because of the internet connection the libraries won't have been downloaded correctly. Then you can follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443297/xamarin-forms-android-error-please-install-package-android-support-library).

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is related with the space in your user name:

1) C:\Users\Zeeshan Ahmad

### Your user name have a Space, that generate problems with VS. and Xamarin.

You can prove that this is true, creating a new user with a simple name without space a character specials and installing the VS2015 and xamarin and compiling again.